# Sending messages to gerrit from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I have a voter project in Jenkins triggered by a gerrit event.My task is to figure out how send additional messages to gerrit (apart from the automatically sent by voters) during a build or after it with information regarding build status or which steps/tasks were successful.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question. I want those messages/notifications to apear beside the jenkins job link in the gerrit code review history as the build failure analyzer does it.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can send messages using [Command Line Tools](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-index.html). Something like that would work..

> ssh -p $GERRIT_PORT $GERRIT_HOST gerrit review --project
>   "$GERRIT_PROJECT" --message '"Custom message"'
>   "$GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION"

In order to include a variable in the message we would evaluate the command first.

> eval ssh -p $GERRIT_PORT $GERRIT_HOST gerrit review --project
>   "$GERRIT_PROJECT" --message \'\"Custom message. $BUILD_URL\"\'
>   "$GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION"